# How to stop the execution of a socket event when any user response to the event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, notifications, uber-api

I'm trying to develop a doctor-calling system like Uber for my university project. In this system, when a patient clicks a specific UI button in his app, a socket event, `CallingForEmergencyDoctor` is emitted.

When this event is triggered I receive it in the server and send a real-time notification/call to the Doctor app by emitting an event `emergencyDoctorCall`

According to my requirement, a doctor should only get the notification/call/alert for 5 sec. If the doctor does not answer the call, this event needs to be emitted to another doctor. In the meantime, if any doctor accepts the call, no other doctor will receive the call/notification.

I make an array, `activeEmergencyDoctors` containing all the active online doctors and emit the event using a loop. Then I use a `sleep` function to delay the time. Then after 5 sec, I emit  another event `emergencyCallDisconnect` to the doctor to disconnect the call and disappear the accept button from the doctor's UI

```
 socket.on("CallingForEmergencyDoctor", (user) => {

    // send event to a specific user at a time
    for (let i = 0; i < activeEmergencyDoctors.length; i++) {
      socket.to(activeEmergencyDoctors[i].socketId).emit("emergencyDoctorCall");
      userId = activeEmergencyDoctors[i].userId;
      console.log(
        `Request sent to user ${i + 1} | userId: ${
          activeEmergencyDoctors[i].userId
        }`
      );
      sleep(5000);
      socket
        .to(activeEmergencyDoctors[i].socketId)
        .emit("emergencyCallDisconnect");
    }
    console.log("No doctor available");
  });
```

Everything is ok, every doctor is receiving call one after another. But how can I stop the execution of the for loop and receive the userId who accepts the request?

Comment: There are likely a number of issues with this type of implementation, not the least of which is the `sleep()` function.  But, you can break out of the loop by setting a flag that you check after the `sleep()` function which tells you whether you got a response and if you did, you can then break the `for` loop.

Comment: General issues with this: 1) `sleep()` function unless used with promises and `await` is not how you do something on a server in nodejs, 2) How does this code handle multiple incoming `CallingForEmergencyDoctor` messages from different clients?  Which doctors does each one iterate through?  3) Presumably doctors can come and go from being on call so you need to be able to handle `activeEmergencyDoctors` changing dynamically while you're iterating it.

Comment: what should be the best practice to make this type of system?